# OpenSSL support for Ruby: "Cipher is not a module (TypeError)"

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, ruby, phusion-passenger, openssl

### The Problem

Our systems admin needed to upgrade the packages on our CentOS 5.4 dev server to match the packages on our production server. The upgrade affected **ruby** and/or **openssl**.

We run a Ruby on Rails issue tracking system called [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) that is deployed with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com) on Apache. Everything worked before the server update, but when trying to access the ticket system now, I get the following error:

#### Error message:

```
Cipher is not a module
```

#### Exception class:

```
TypeError
```

#### Application root:

```
/home/dev/rails/redmine-0.8.7
```

I've been trying so hard to fix this problem but I can't seem to beat it.

I have tried following this guide:
http://iamclovin.posterous.com/how-to-solve-the-cipher-is-not-a-module-error

When I try `require 'openssl'` in IRB, I do see a `true` return value. However, I'm still seeing the Cipher.rb is not a module TypeError when accessing the ticket system.

#### Possibly (probably) related:

I've tried updating Passenger, but when I try `passenger-install-apache2-module` I see:

```
Checking for required software...

* GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
* Ruby development headers... found
* OpenSSL support for Ruby... /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/cipher.rb:22: Cipher is not a module (TypeError)
```

#### Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [x86_64-linux]

#### in ruby source directory

```
cd ext/openssl/
ruby extconf.rb 
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -R /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/openssl* /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/
```

Finding a fix for this took a very long time...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just having the same, had to compile my ruby myself, what fedora has is 1.8.6

Comment: An additional comment that if the above does not fix the issue then look at the bang header (first line) on your ruby scripts. On Ubuntu most system-wide ruby scripts run with `ruby1.8`!! If you manually installed ruby 1.8.7 then it will not overwrite `ruby1.8`, and you'll have your old scripts still running your old ruby version even if you just installed 1.8.7, and you'll still be getting the openssl error. The fix is to link `ruby1.8 -> ruby`, or change the bang header of your ruby scripts to run the correct ruby (`/usr/bin/ruby`).